# Can not make a phone call in test

Tags: firebase-test-lab

I have made a phone call in my android instrumentation test in test-lab, but it failed because the device in the test-lab can't connect to the mobile web.  How to solve it?

Comment: Normal phone calls aren't made over "the mobile web".  They're made using cellular service provided by a mobile service provider when a SIM card is installed.  The devices in Test Lab don't have SIM cards, and therefore don't have a mobile service provider.  They have wifi access.  Are you expecting this phone call to be made over wifi?

Comment: @DougStevenson OK, then how to make a phone over wifi?

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend asking on the official Slack channel (firebase-community.slack.com, #test-lab), since the Firebase Test Lab eng team can directly look at your test runs. There are also other users that may have run into the same issues as you.